# Page Specific filter for SharePoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell, modern-pages, modern-document-library

**Hello Friends,**

I have different pages on my SharePoint online site and one document library. I would like to display the document library with different filters. However, I would like a different filters data on each of the pages. So, when each page is navigated to, there is a documents web part displaying a unique view and filters. I am working in SharePoint online and modern page. I tried to use PnP Powershell script to achieve this but there is no luck.

**Problem** - When apply filter on document library for page specific, then same filter getting applied for all the pages. I want filers to be page specific. please help me if any work around for this. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Document Library web part allows us to select which list view is displayed in the current web part. See the reference here: [Use the Document Library web part.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0)

You can save the filters in separated list views and then display only one list view using this web part on each page. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Can we do the filtering based on the Query String fields?